# Export highcharts / stockchart to image did not same as in web browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, highcharts

I tried to setup exporting to image function by call

```
chart.exportChart({
      type: 'image/png',
      filename: linechart.chartName
    });
```

But the result is not same with expected.

We expected the image exported same with chart viewed in web browser.

I tried some setting for exportChart function to have export image same as chart viewed in web browser but not success.

I also tried to use some external library like dom-to-imge or html2canvas but it is not same 100%.

This is chart view in web browser

[image]

And this is exported chart by exportChart function

[image]

Can you suggest setting for export to image where the exported image same as view in browser like screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: It looks really strange. Could you reproduce it in online code editor like codesandbox? Check this example with exporting: https://codesandbox.io/s/8y14q1kxoj. You can use it as a template.

Comment: Because it use API and angular, the logic is quite complex so it is not easy to create example

Comment: Ok, I understand it. However, try to simplify it, use sample data and settings just to reproduce this particular issue as simple as possible.